# Splitting cell contents to just return the date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I download this report that gives me the date and clock in time for employees. An example of a cell from the report contains 9/1/2020 8:00:00 AM

I'm trying to get a formula that can extract the date only. The dates range from the 1st of the month to the last of the month so the length of them varies depending on if it's within the first 10 days of the month.

What's the easiest way to write a formula to do this?

Comment: `=TEXT(A1, "M/D/YYYY")`

Comment: are the dates stored as strings or are they true dates?  When you test with `=ISNUMBER(A1)` where `A1` is the cell, does it return `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: It returns True. Mech's answer works too so thank you. Also someone else asked a similar question 4 years ago as linked over my initial post. Thanks for the assistance